# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred for failure result type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

This seems common question over here but none of the explanations or solutions for other questions have really helped me.

I have a following `protocol` with generic func inside,

```
public protocol SomeProtocol: class {
func myResult<T: Codable>(_ result: Result<T, IntParsingError>)
}
```

and I'm calling this as follow,

```
@IBAction func sendSuccess(_ sender: Any) {
    someProtocol?.myResult(.success(SampleData(str: "Foo")))
}

@IBAction func sendError(_ sender: Any) {
    someProtocol?. myResult(.failure(.overflow)) 
}

public enum IntParsingError: Error {
    case overflow
}
```

`SendSuccess` works fine but for `sendError` I get compilation error `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `sendSuccess`, the compiler can infer `T` because it sees that you passed a `SampleData` into `.success`. The parameter of `.success` is `T`, so `T` must be `SampleData`.

For `sendError`, the compiler has no way to know what `T` is, based solely on:

```
someProtocol?.myResult(.failure(.overflow))
```

The `.failure` case does not tell the compiler what type `T` is. `.failure(.overflow)` could be a value of type `Result<Int, IntParsingError>`, or `Result<String, IntParsingError>` or `Result<SomeRidiculousType, IntParsingError>`.

You can specify the type of `Result` like this:

```
// for example, if you want a T to be SampleData like in sendSuccess
someProtocol?.myResult(Result<SampleData, IntParsingError>.failure(.overflow))
```

That said, I have a feeling that `myResult` shouldn't be generic at all. A method that is able to handle `Result`s of any type seems a little weird, but I don't know what your actual situation is, so I can't comment any further.

Comment: According to the requirement I have to go for generic type but thanks for explanation now it all makes sense. Let me try the solution and see if it works.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for clarifying the error. Appreciated!